# Audio in Phaser not working - Cant Hear Sound

Tags: javascript, audio, game-development, phaser-framework

I'm relatively new to Phaser and can't seem to get my audio working. It says 'Playing: true' up top and I see the time incrementing so I think I loaded it correctly. I am using chrome (mp3 should be fine).

Here is the relevant code:

```
const game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
  preload: preload,
  create: create,
  update: update,
  render: render
})

let music

function preload () {
  game.load.audio('jackpot', 'jackpot.mp3')
}

function create () {
   ....

   game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE)
   music = game.add.audio('jackpot')
   music.loop = true
   music.play()
}


function render() {
  game.debug.soundInfo(music, 20, 32)
}
```

I have my sound up yet still can't hear anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is `jackpot.mp3` in the same directory as your JavaScript file? Your example is almost identical to [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/audio/play-music) of Phaser, so code wise there is not much to improve. Are you able to create a workable example for us to debug?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier it's in the same directory as my other public assets which are getting loaded just fine (pngs)